How to Make Ubuntu on a Portable SSD Truly Hardware-Agnostic Across AMD, Intel, nvidia Systems?
As discussed in Can Ubuntu adapt itself automatically when there is a hardware change?, Ubuntu can detect changes in hardware and apply appropriate configurations.
I have Ubuntu installed on a portable SSD, and my goal is to make it truly portable, allowing me to plug it into any x64 hardware and have it work seamlessly. In this scenario, every component except the storage could potentially change between systems.  plan to use this drive primarily on my personal PC, and when I travel, carry the SSD to use with any PC or laptop. The expected workload includes running software and tools such as code editors, Android emulators, compilers, Docker, and similar development tools.
This is different from question Fully functional, architecture-agnostic portable USB Ubuntu installation? about making a live USB with persistent storage, as I am working with a full Ubuntu installation on a portable SSD.
Here are my questions:

Is it technically practical to achieve this level of portability, assuming all hardware is Linux-compatible?
What steps should I take when migrating the SSD to a new device to ensure smooth operation?
Can Ubuntu keep multiple drivers (e.g., NVIDIA, AMD, Intel) and microcodes installed and dynamically switch between them based on the detected hardware? This would eliminate the need to download and install drivers every time I change devices.
What considerations should I keep in mind to achieve optimal performance, especially for resource-intensive tasks like Docker or emulators?


PS: This question is not same as Installing Ubuntu 20.04 to a USB pen drive (256 GB) with NVIDIA Drivers. The goal there is to create three separate boot options for loading specific driver versions. My query is different because I'm looking to make a single installation of Ubuntu that can adapt to any hardware platform without being tied to specific drivers. Creating separate drives or boot options for each hardware combination wouldn't solve this

This question is similar to: Installing Ubuntu 20.04 to a USB pen drive (256 GB) with NVIDIA Drivers. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The recommendation there^ is to have separate installations for each of the proprietary drivers on the same disk, and switch between them as needed.

Thanks for pointing that out! That question seems similar, but the goal there is to create three separate boot options for loading specific driver versions. My query is different because I'm looking to make a single installation of Ubuntu that can adapt to any hardware platform without being tied to specific drivers. Creating separate drives or boot options for each hardware combination wouldn't solve this.

An installed system isn't intended to be used in every possible combination; as some hardware requires specific blacklist that will prevent other systems from booting the same system. Multiple grub options allow you to change many settings, but only boot settings and not all settings can be configured at boot. Booting a live system (with or without persistence) is more flexible; but still isn't 100% flexible either.

@Salitha I got your query, but you seem to miss the point that OP there has actually ran into trouble because of having multiple proprietary drivers installed, and that's why multiple installations is recommended. That's part of the trouble with proprietary drivers - they're maintained outside of the kernel independently of each other, so there's no requirement and probably no effort put into making them play nice with each other.

To achieve it (if you don't understand what @muru & myself are trying to say) is you'd need to make changes to the system prior to shutdown considering the next machine you'll boot it on, so that you configure the system so that it'll boot correctly (esp. where closed source kernel modules are required - ie. hardware specific) and add/remove the entries in blacklist etc so specific kernel modules will be used, and others will NOT be used as mandated by the next machine you'll boot on. Boot or grub parameters can only changes some kernel options; the rest being edits to files on the disk

Thanks for the comments! YOLO, so it’s worth trying, right?
On a more serious note, I understand that aiming for 'EVERY' hardware is a bit ambitious. However, in my experience, it usually works to some extent - you can at least log in, even if performance isn’t optimal. My goal is to understand where the boundary lies and what steps can make the system better once logged in.
I believe Linux in general is capable, if you configure things correctly after booting on a new system. TBH, I've tested it with AMD and Intel laptops, and it’s been fairly smooth unless there’s a specific issue.

Its my opinion that Linux is capable where all open source modules are used; it's the closed-source models (which @muru made very clear I felt; nVIDIA being classic example of these) that make the assumption of a single-machine boot configuration that will prevent operation in other machines, when configured with specific modules. You mention AMD & Intel which do well with open source generally; nVIDIA don't all work well with nouveau (the open source module) thus requiring blacklist of open source modules that most machines work well with

@Salitha if you're goal is to find out to what extend things work, then the only thing to do is actually try it out, because there's no guarantee of anything with proprietary drivers.
